# How to display the child Grids inside the container Grid to the next line retaining the space and wrapping the grid according to the text?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, grid

Below the component contains a parent grid inside which 2 other child grids are present .I was tryin to implement a hardcoded chat UI and I have also tried using sm md properties but this discards the feature of the grid being wrapped according to the text content in it. Using the sm md properties makes the grid to a constant width which may not be completely filled using the text as the text length keep changing.

```
export const Chats = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Grid container display={"wrap"} justifyContent={"space-between"}>
        <Grid
          style={{
            backgroundColor: "white",
            padding: "10px",
            marginTop: "100px",
            borderRadius:"10px"
          }}
        >
          <Box>
            <Typography>This is message 1 </Typography>
          </Box>
        </Grid>
        <Grid
          style={{
            backgroundColor: "#E3F6CB",
            padding: "10px",
            marginTop: "100px",
            borderRadius:"10px"

          }}
        >
          <Typography>This is message 2</Typography>
        </Grid>
      
      </Grid>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: You should be using `<Grid item ...`  for the child grids e.g. `<Grid item xs={8}>`
See the [basic setup](https://mui.com/components/grid/#basic-grid)

Comment: I have tried the same, but this discards the property of grid being wrapped according to the text content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the styling CSS property " display: inline-flex " as shown below to make sure that the dynamic text content gets wrapped by the Grid. Make sure to use multiple grid containers for each chat box being created. Make sure to use the predefined properties in material UI for the same as shown below.

```
export const Chats = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Grid container xs={12} style={{ display: "inline-flex" }}>
        <Grid item xs={6}>
          <Box
            style={{
              backgroundColor: "white",
              padding: "10px",
              marginTop: "100px",
              borderRadius: "10px",
              display: "inline-flex",
            }}
          >
           This is message 1
          </Box>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={6}></Grid>
      </Grid>
      <Grid container  justifyContent={"space-between"}>
        <Grid item ></Grid>

        <Grid  item >
          <Box
            style={{
              backgroundColor: "#E3F6CB",
              padding: "10px",
              borderRadius: "10px",
              display: "inline-flex",
            }}
          >
           This is message 2
          </Box>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </>
  );
};
```